# Launcher on Android Operating system

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-os-handler

I have created an android application. I want to display only that application on a tablet and not any other application from the android operating system. I know that happens by creating a launcher. The scenario is, I have to place that tablet on a door where I do not want to give controls to external users and also do not want any other application which is provided by Android Operating system. Can anyone briefly explain how can I proceed to create such a system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably check out [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=2068084). Also try to Google for [Android Kiosk mode](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices)